# Registery equivalent or windows command to fetch values for various settings of software restriction policies in windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-registry

How can we fetch values of various settings available under software restriction policies in windows 2003. I tried using `secpol.msc` but it is only give us a GUI then we need to navigate to individual settings to check their value.

Actually we have a requirement of compliance check as per our organization standards and every settings under software restriction policies need to be in sync with the standards. Since we have huge no. of servers, manual check for these settings will be very difficult to manage. I am looking  for some windows command or registry equivalent settings. so that we can build some script to check the respective parameters value and modify them if required (in case they does not match with the standards)

Below are the settings that we are looking for

- Software Restriction Policies/Security Levels
- Software Restriction Policies/Additional rules
- Software Restriction Policies/Enforcement
- Software Restriction Policies/Trusted publishers
- Software Restriction Policies/Designated File Types

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Software Restriction Policy settings are stored in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\safer
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\safer
```

You can find [reasonable detailed background on the registry values used from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786941(v=ws.10).aspx). Your path rules, for example, will be stored under one of those keys.

Comment: thanks Evan Anderson for your quick response. But I have already verified http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786941(v=ws.10).aspx . I am not getting the exact settings under that. Means which registry setting is for for which software restriction policies setting. Like what would be the exact equivalent setting for - Software Restriction Policies/Enforcement

Comment: can you just point me to the exact path/ doc, if any.